# Is there a more efficient way to create a Grouped list

Tags: linq, listview, grouping

I want to create a grouped list of NEW, DELETED, COMMON Items.  I currently do it this way:

```
public class ListSortingGroupingTest
{
    List<int> OldList = new List<int> { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };
    List<int> NewList = new List<int> { 3, 4, 5, 7, 8, 9 };

    public void CreateGroupedList()
    {
        var deleted = OldList.Except(NewList).Select(i => new { Group = "Deleted", Number = i });
        var added = NewList.Except(OldList).Select(i => new { Group = "Added", Number = i});
        var common = NewList.Intersect(OldList).Select(i => new { Group = "Common", Number = i});

        var result = deleted.Union(added).Union(common);

    }
}
```

This works. But I wondered if there was a better or more efficient way?

Ultimately I wish to bind to this in a WPF Grouped ListView.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your current approach is the standard and natural way of extracting the information for changes between old and new set (i.e. unique sequence) of values. The LINQ set operators used (`Except` and `Intersect`) are quite efficient due to hash lookup based implementation. Although the 3 calls will create internally 3 hash sets, the complexity will be still `O(N+M)`. The only improvement would be to use `Concat` instead of `Union`, since the previous methods would uniquely separate the values.

A bit more efficient way (but still `O(N+M)`) could be to concatenate the old and new items with additional property specifying if the value is old or new, then group by value and determine the added/deleted/common state base on the grouping count and content - groups with 2 values are the common, and for groups with single value the added/deleted depends on if the value is new or old:

```
var result = OldList.Select(x => new { Value = x, IsNew = false })
    .Concat(NewList.Select(x => new { Value = x, IsNew = true }))
    .GroupBy(x => x.Value)
    .Select(g => new
    {
        Group = g.Count() > 1 ? "Common" : g.First().IsNew ? "Added" : "Deleted",
        Number = g.Key
    });
```

Comment: Fantastic answer and provably more efficient.  I ran a stopwatch over both my and your implementation with the following results:   ME => Time To Execute: 16954(6ms)
YOU => Time To Execute: 1321(0ms)

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
var result = OldList.Union(NewList).Select(n => new
        {
            Group = OldList.Contains(n) && NewList.Contains(n) ? "Common" : (OldList.Contains(n)) ? "Deleted" : "Added",
            Number = n
        }).ToList();
```